# Kafka consumer: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming

I want to read messages from Kafka queue in Python. For example, in Scala it's quite easy to do:

```
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(20))

    // Divide the topic into partitions
    val topicMessages = "myKafkaTopic"
    val topicMessagesMap = topicMessages.split(",").map((_, kafkaNumThreads)).toMap

    val messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMessagesMap).map(_._2)

    messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      //...
    }
```

I want to do just the same in Python. This is my current Python code:

```
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)

topicMessages = "myKafkaTopic"
topicMessagesMap = topicMessages.split(",").map((_, kafkaNumThreads)).toMap

messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMessagesMap)
```

However I get the error at the line `topicMessagesMap = topicMessages.split(",").map((_, kafkaNumThreads)).toMap`:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

How to make this code working?

**UPDATE:**

If I run this code in Jupyter Notebook, then I get the error shown below:

```
messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {inputKafkaTopic: list})
```

> Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one
>   of the following.
>
> 1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
>       spark-submit command as
>
>    $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.0.0 ...
> 2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
>       Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, Version = 2.0.0.
>       Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as
>
>    $ bin/spark-submit --jars  ...

Do I understand correctly that the only way to make it working is to use `spark-submit` and it's impossible to run this code from Jupyter/IPython?

Comment: What is `toMap` supposed to do? You can't just copy and paste code from I one language to another like that; it's just a coincidence that the rest of that line works.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Yes, you are right. The problem is that I cannot find how to divide the topic into partitions in Python. I saw that there is kafka-python api, but I'd like to use the one provided by `pyspark.streaming`.